Cordova Android file cordova.gradle reporting "No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 30.0.3"
I am trying to get my Ionic/Cordova Android build working on my Windows 11 machine.
I have installed everything I thought I needed to (Android Studio, Java, JSK) etc.
I have the following installed
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\33.0.3
And I have this set

I have gone into the cordova.gradle where the error is being reported, and added a few more lines into the message, so I now have
 if (highestBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("""
        No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools
        version ${minBuildToolsVersionString}. minBuildToolsVersion" ${minBuildToolsVersionString} 
        maxVersion: ${minBuildToolsVersion.getMajor() + 1} buildbuildToolsDirContents ${buildToolsDirContents}
    """.replaceAll(/\s+/, ' ').trim())
}

I get the following printed out....
No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 30.0.3. minBuildToolsVersion" 30.0.3 maxVersion: 31 buildbuildToolsDirContents [33.0.0, 33.0.3]
So is IS finding the 33.0.3 as one of the folders, but I don't underdstand this following line which is returning null....
   def highestBuildToolsVersion = buildToolsDirContents
    .collect { new Version(it) }
    // Invalid inputs will be handled as 0.0.0
    .findAll { it.isHigherThan('0.0.0') && it.isLowerThan(maxVersion) }
    .max()

Anyone have any idea what the above line is (I Have no idea what language this is), and why it is returning null?

Would still like to know why the above did not work, but got around it by adding <preference name="android-buildToolsVersion" value="30.0.3" /> to config.xml. Now the next problem! It really is terrible how frail it is!
